# "Failed to unarchive element named UITableViewController"

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I've been following the "Build your second iOS app" tutorial step for step and I have run into this error after the tutorial promised that all the errors would go away, but the error didn't show up until after the other errors were all corrected and I tried to compile it.

The error:

```
The document "MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard" could not be opened. Failed to unarchive element named "UITableViewController".
```

Here is a link to the [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/CustomizingDetailView/CustomizingDetailView.html).

Here is my storyboard in XML format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="1.1" toolsVersion="2182" systemVersion="11D50" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" initialViewController="3">
<dependencies>
    <deployment defaultVersion="1296" identifier="iOS"/>
    <development defaultVersion="4200" identifier="xcode"/>
    <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="1179"/>
</dependencies>
<scenes>
    <!--Navigation Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="11">
        <objects>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="10" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            <navigationController id="3" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <navigationBar key="navigationBar" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="4">
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                </navigationBar>
                <connections>
                    <segue destination="12" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController" id="19"/>
                </connections>
            </navigationController>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="-1" y="64"/>
    </scene>
    <!--Hello World Master View Controller - Master-->
    <scene sceneID="18">
        <objects>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="17" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            <tableViewController storyboardIdentifier="" title="Master" id="12" customClass="HelloWorldMasterViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <tableView key="view" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" clearsContextBeforeDrawing="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" rowHeight="44" sectionHeaderHeight="22" sectionFooterHeight="22" id="13">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="64" width="320" height="416"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    <prototypes>
                        <tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="blue" accessoryType="disclosureIndicator" hidesAccessoryWhenEditing="NO" indentationLevel="1" indentationWidth="0.0" reuseIdentifier="BirdSightingCell" textLabel="phq-AM-6qj" detailTextLabel="d2j-B0-0IP" style="IBUITableViewCellStyleSubtitle" id="lJ0-d7-vTF">
                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="22" width="320" height="44"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                            <view key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="300" height="43"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="left" text="Bird Sightings" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="phq-AM-6qj">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="10" y="2" width="123" height="22"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="18"/>
                                        <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                                        <color key="highlightedColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                    </label>
                                    <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="left" text="Subtitle" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="d2j-B0-0IP">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="10" y="24" width="47" height="18"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                                        <color key="textColor" red="0.50196078431372548" green="0.50196078431372548" blue="0.50196078431372548" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                        <color key="highlightedColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                    </label>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                            </view>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                            <connections>
                                <segue destination="21" kind="push" identifier="ShowSightingDetails" id="w1o-hR-DXB"/>
                            </connections>
                        </tableViewCell>
                    </prototypes>
                    <sections/>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="dataSource" destination="12" id="16"/>
                        <outlet property="delegate" destination="12" id="15"/>
                    </connections>
                </tableView>
                <navigationItem key="navigationItem" title="Bird Sightings" id="36"/>
            </tableViewController>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="459" y="64"/>
    </scene>
    <!--Hello World Detail View Controller - Detail-->
    <scene sceneID="24">
        <objects>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="23" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            <viewController storyboardIdentifier="" title="Detail" id="21" customClass="HelloWorldDetailViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="22">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="64" width="320" height="416"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="static" style="plain" rowHeight="44" sectionHeaderHeight="22" sectionFooterHeight="22" id="bJd-7W-8nV">
                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="445"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                            <sections>
                                <tableViewSection headerTitle="" id="Ihs-Gj-deH">
                                    <cells>
                                        <tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="blue" hidesAccessoryWhenEditing="NO" indentationLevel="1" indentationWidth="0.0" id="6ax-NG-pEn">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="44"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <view key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="43"/>
                                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                                <subviews>
                                                    <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" text="Bird Name:" textAlignment="right" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" minimumFontSize="10" id="eba-dh-Ofl">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="20" y="11" width="125" height="21"/>
                                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="17"/>
                                                        <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                                                        <color key="highlightedColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                                    </label>
                                                    <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" text="Label" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" minimumFontSize="10" id="PBz-NZ-g9m">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="153" y="11" width="147" height="21"/>
                                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                        <color key="textColor" white="0.66666666666666663" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                                        <color key="highlightedColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                                    </label>
                                                </subviews>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                            </view>
                                        </tableViewCell>
                                    </cells>
                                </tableViewSection>
                                <tableViewSection headerTitle="" id="YGG-h0-ybX">
                                    <cells>
                                        <tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="blue" hidesAccessoryWhenEditing="NO" indentationLevel="1" indentationWidth="0.0" id="oYs-Dm-zlN">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="44" width="320" height="44"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <view key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="43"/>
                                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                                <subviews>
                                                    <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" text="Location:" textAlignment="right" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" minimumFontSize="10" id="mbD-Wl-CEY">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="20" y="11" width="125" height="21"/>
                                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="17"/>
                                                        <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                                                        <color key="highlightedColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                                    </label>
                                                    <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" text="Label" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" minimumFontSize="10" id="A69-jC-WXb">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="153" y="11" width="147" height="21"/>
                                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                        <color key="textColor" white="0.66666666666666663" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                                        <color key="highlightedColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                                    </label>
                                                </subviews>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                            </view>
                                        </tableViewCell>
                                    </cells>
                                </tableViewSection>
                                <tableViewSection headerTitle="" id="zi6-o7-XN3">
                                    <cells>
                                        <tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="blue" hidesAccessoryWhenEditing="NO" indentationLevel="1" indentationWidth="0.0" id="gsv-CZ-0go">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="88" width="320" height="44"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <view key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="43"/>
                                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                                <subviews>
                                                    <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" text="Date:" textAlignment="right" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" minimumFontSize="10" id="K2s-9i-tfj">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="20" y="11" width="125" height="21"/>
                                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="17"/>
                                                        <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                                                        <color key="highlightedColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                                    </label>
                                                    <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" text="Label" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" minimumFontSize="10" id="PTf-Ge-Hjf">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="153" y="11" width="147" height="21"/>
                                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                        <color key="textColor" white="0.66666666666666663" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                                        <color key="highlightedColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                                    </label>
                                                </subviews>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                            </view>
                                        </tableViewCell>
                                    </cells>
                                </tableViewSection>
                            </sections>
                        </tableView>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                </view>
                <navigationItem key="navigationItem" title="Sightings" id="26"/>
                <connections>
                    <outlet property="lblBirdName" destination="PBz-NZ-g9m" id="KgV-rg-2MY"/>
                    <outlet property="lblDate" destination="PTf-Ge-Hjf" id="Scy-nS-Sot"/>
                    <outlet property="lblLocation" destination="A69-jC-WXb" id="hwm-Zv-8QE"/>
                </connections>
            </viewController>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="902" y="64"/>
    </scene>
</scenes>
<classes>
    <class className="HelloWorldDetailViewController" superclassName="UITableViewController">
        <source key="sourceIdentifier" type="project" relativePath="./Classes/HelloWorldDetailViewController.h"/>
        <relationships>
            <relationship kind="outlet" name="lblBirdName" candidateClass="UILabel"/>
            <relationship kind="outlet" name="lblDate" candidateClass="UILabel"/>
            <relationship kind="outlet" name="lblLocation" candidateClass="UILabel"/>
        </relationships>
    </class>
    <class className="HelloWorldMasterViewController" superclassName="UITableViewController">
        <source key="sourceIdentifier" type="project" relativePath="./Classes/HelloWorldMasterViewController.h"/>
    </class>
</classes>
<simulatedMetricsContainer key="defaultSimulatedMetrics">
    <simulatedStatusBarMetrics key="statusBar"/>
    <simulatedOrientationMetrics key="orientation"/>
    <simulatedScreenMetrics key="destination"/>
</simulatedMetricsContainer>
</document>
```

I am completely new to objective c and Xcode so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or even really where to begin with an error like that. If anyone knows how to fix this error, or a better (online) resource for learning both objective c and iOS development at the same time, I would really appreciate either one.

[Here](http://singularity-id.com/Birds.zip) is my project if anyone wants to take a look at it for me.

Comment: I should probably add that I am using Xcode 4.3 on Lion in case that is relevant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to find out what I did wrong on the tutorial. Rather than drag the TableViewController and delete the DetailViewController I dragged a table onto the controller on top of the detail view. I'm not sure how I missed that, I must have been really tired yesterday.

Also, anyone who is stuck on the apple iPhone development tutorial, I highly recommend the "Stanford iPhone development" series on iTunes. I'm going through it right now and it is amazing. It explains things that the apple tutorial never did (like when to use strong vs weak in properties, atomic vs nonatomic also in properties). I know I'm starting to understand objective c because I actually know what to google when I get stuck.