# Failed to un-archive element named stackview

Tags: xamarin, ios9, xcode7.1

I am building an app in iOS 9. I have set the deployment target to 9.1 and using xCode 7 with Xamarin 5.9.7. While running the app, I am getting the error which is attached image.[image]

[image]

Tried a lot of stuff but no luck. Please help me out.

Comment: This might give you a hint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626286/failed-to-unarchive-element-named-uitableviewcontroller

Comment: Thanks @RIYAZ I tried the same and now the issue is somehow gone but new issue has been appeared. But I am guessing these issues are because of xamarin.ios 9.4 update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems like you are using existing project in iOS9, You must create new project and transfer all your existing file into new project. It should work now.